# Mobile Website Control Panel App

Tags: ios

My friend owns a web-hosting company and is starting to make a Control Panel from scratch (quite a feat). He wants to have a mobile version of it so his customers can access their website panel wherever they are. He asked me if I could make such an app. I have only made a few very basic apps that I never published on the app store, just used for personal Enjoyment. I have 2 questions.

1) Is this even remotely possible for an Amateur developer?

2) What would I need to do this sort of thing? (please answer even if the above question is "no")

Really my question is, resources do I need from my friend (i.e. databases) to make an app like this, and would it be reasonable for me to even attempt something like this.

Comment: This question is rather general. Maybe add other tags to question appropriately. This is not an iOS question.

Comment: What kind of question is it then?

Comment: This question is rather broad and can lead to a subjective discussion which ultimately means that it is probably not a question suited for this site.

Comment: Well, um, where else would you suggest I go? This seemed like the perfect place to ask that question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible, most iOS apps I have worked on do this. You friend will have to create a web API for the service being provided. You will then have to post URL requests to the Web API to make changes or get data to display, basically your friend has to write web pages that are JSON (or XML) instead of HTML, JSON is the the most popular format to return data from Web APIs for iOS apps. For pushing data to the web you can either do a GET with query values or a PUT with a body containing JSON, it is up to your friend to decide these things, it can change from one request type to the next. Googling 'cocoa touch web service' returned lots of tutorials and libraries that can be of help.